How do I set Firebase database rules to only allow write data to authenticated and non-disabled accounts
I am currently writing a chat application online, and I want to make it so only accounts that are authorized and not disabled can write messages.
In the future I want to be able to disable accounts on the go.
Once I disable the account, if the user goes to send a message, currently they are able to. I would like it to only allow write data for authenticated and non-disabled users.
I currently have the code as:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}

I have tried using the following:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if auth.token.email_verified == true && auth.token.email.matches(/.*@gmail.com);
    }
  }
}

and have tried this...
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth == auth.uid;
    }
  }
}

I am unsure what I need to place inside the rules file for only authenticated and non-disabled accounts can write new messages.
So within the Firebase database, the rule file needs to be changed to allow only authenticated, and non-disabled users to allow to write data (aka: sending messages).
So the only people who can write messages are authenticated users, and user accounts that are not disabled.
Thank you to everyone who has seen this messaged, and have tried to help!

The Firebase security rules have access to all information that exists in the ID token of the user. Disabling an account (in the Firebase console or through the API) makes it impossible to mint new ID tokens for that account, but doesn't change anything about existing ID tokens (those can't be modified after they're minted).
If you want to be able to instantly disable access, you'll need to use another mechanism. The documentation on detecting ID token revocation shows one such mechanism which tracks the UID of the disabled user account in some secondary data source that the security rules can access. The documentation uses Realtime Database, but using Firestore would work too.
